# Nvidia GTX 1050 ti on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

I just upgraded my graphics card to the GTX 1050 Ti, the screen works fine, but I don't seem to be capable of using the GPU with Caffe or Cuda.

lucie02@lucie02:~$ lspci | grep VGA 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c82 (rev a1)

Can some one Please help.

Answer (score 4):

As of 14 March 2017, adding zesty to your apt sources:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
```

and `apt-get install nvidia-375` appears to work and not drag in unrelated packages from zesty. Consider it experimental (zesty isn't due to release for another month) but perhaps less troublesome than the full purge-and-upstream approach that you'd have previously needed.

Comment: So is the answer.  I've literally been installing the zesty nvidia packages on my trusty systems.  (Of course, since then I've discovered that nvidia has their own debs that are actually built for 14.04...)

Comment: You're correct. I should have read the question more attentively. +1

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the version 375.20 driver for my GTX 1050 Ti graphics card on Ubuntu 16.04 with difficulty for my ASUS E3 Pro Gaming V5 mainboard. And I had installed the Cuda run(local) file to test the Cuda samples which work fine. So I think the GTX 1050 Ti also support Cuda on your environment of Ubuntu 14.04.

There is a very valuable article for introducing how to install/uninstall Nvidia Driver 375.20 on Ubuntu/Other Linux distributions, and the supported Ubuntu version list includes 14.04. It can truly help for you, please move to the [link](http://www.askmetutorials.com/2016/11/install-uninstall-nvidia-driver-37520.html) to see the installation steps.

> 1. Remove the older version of Nvidia driver
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
>    ```
> 2. Reboot the system
> 3. Download the Nvidia Driver 375.20
>
>    For 32bit
>
>    ```
>    wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/375.20/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-375.20.run
>    ```
>
>    For 64 bit
>
>    ```
>    wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/375.20/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run`
>    ```
> 4. Switch to command prompt and stop the running Graphics session.
>      Press Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6 for switching to command prompt
>
>    ```
>    sudo service lightdm stop
>    sudo service gdm stop
>    ```
> 5. Give execute permissions to the installer
>
>    ```
>    sudo chmod 755 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run
>    ```
> 6. Install the Nvidia 375.20 driver
>
>    ```
>    sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run
>    ```
>
>    After successfull installation reboot the system.

Following the steps above, I got some issues which you also will meet.

1. If you have two OS on machine, please disable the `Fast Boot` in Windows & BIOS.
2. If the mainboard enabled `Secure Boot` in BIOS, please disable it. If not, the issue about login loop will still happen. The solution is uninstall the driver via press `Ctrl+Alt+F1~F6` in the command line and reboot to disable secure boot and reinstall it.
3. The nvidia driver [367.xx](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/105343/en-us) & [370.xx](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/107408/en-us) within Cuda run file & apt source not support GTX 1050 Ti, please see the `SUPPORTED PRODUCTS` tab of the links. So please install the supported nvidia driver alone, not via cuda installation or `apt-get install` for nvidia-367/370.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia now has Version: 390.25, and it does support 1050 Ti

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/130646/en-us